# Error in Terraform: Can't configure values for "at_rest_encryption_enabled" and "transit_encryption_enabled" in aws_elasticache_cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-elasticache, redis-cluster

I'm currently facing a challenge with my **Terraform** configuration while working on the deployment of an Amazon ElastiCache cluster coupled with a global replication group. The primary objective is to ensure both **at-rest** and **in-transit encryption** for the **ElastiCache cluster**

## Here is a snippet of my Terraform configuration, focusing on the relevant resources:

```
resource "aws_elasticache_cluster" "redis_cluster" {
  cluster_id               = var.redis_cluster_name
  engine                   = "redis"
  engine_version           = "6.2"
  node_type                = "cache.t2.small"
  num_cache_nodes          = 1
  parameter_group_name     = "default.redis6.x"
  subnet_group_name        = var.subnet_group_name
  security_group_ids       = [var.security_group_id]
  port                     = 6379

  log_delivery_configuration {
    destination      = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.redis_cluster_logs.name
    destination_type = "cloudwatch-logs"
    log_format       = "text"
    log_type         = "slow-log"
  }

  maintenance_window       = "sun:05:00-sun:06:00"
  snapshot_window          = "01:00-02:00"
  snapshot_retention_limit = 30
}

resource "aws_elasticache_global_replication_group" "{replication_group_identifier}" {
  global_replication_group_id_suffix  = "{unique_suffix}"
  automatic_failover_enabled          = true
  primary_replication_group_id        = aws_elasticache_cluster.{cluster_identifier}.id
  at_rest_encryption_enabled = true
  transit_encryption_enabled = true
}
```

## Applying the Terraform configuration, I encountered the following error:

> Can't configure a value for "at_rest_encryption_enabled": its value will be decided automatically based on the result of applying this configuration. Value for unconfigurable attribute with aws_elasticache_global_replication_group.{replication_group_identifier}, on infra.tf line 537, in resource "aws_elasticache_global_replication_group" "{replication_group_identifier}": transit_encryption_enabled = true

> Can't configure a value for "transit_encryption_enabled": its value will be decided automatically based on the result of applying this configuration. in this script

It seems that I cannot explicitly set values for "at_rest_encryption_enabled" and "transit_encryption_enabled" in the `aws_elasticache_global_replication_group` resource. How can I configure these attributes correctly to enable encryption for my ElastiCache cluster?

I appreciate any assistance or guidance on resolving this issue. If more details are needed, please let me know.

Comment: Please add the rest of the code. There are some limitations for encryption based on what you might have configured.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting encryption limitations, @MarkoE. I've incorporated the changes into the code. Any further insights you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: From what I have seen, only [`elasticache_replication_group`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elasticache_replication_group#at_rest_encryption_enabled) resource has encryption at rest argument. The limitations I mentioned are addressed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/at-rest-encryption.html#at-rest-encryption-constraints.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, @Marko E. I did check the documentation, and you're right about the encryption at rest being specific to the elasticache_replication_group resource.If you have any tips or best practices for implementing encryption in this context, feel free to share them!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elasticache_global_replication_group), you will see that the encryption settings on `aws_elasticache_global_replication_group` are output attributes only. Those are not values you can set.

Looking at the example on that same page, it appears that you need to create a regular `aws_elasticache_replication_group` resource, with the encryptions settings specified on that resource, and then pass that resource to the `aws_elasticache_global_replication_group` as the `primary_replication_group_id`.

You are currently passing an `aws_elasticache_cluster` as the `primary_replication_group_id` which seems wrong. I think you would get an error on that, or at the very least some unexpected behavior.